# How to prive the existence of the root?

Tags: calculus

Prove that between any two roots of $e^x\sin x=1$, there is at least one root of $e^x\cos x+1=0$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be any two roots of $f(x)=e^x\sin x=1$. Now by Mean Value Theorem $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ for some $c\in(a, b)$. So we get $f'(c)=e^c(\sin c+\cos c)=0$ for some $c\in(a, b)$. So $e^c\cos c+1-1+e^c\sin c=0$. From here I don't know hot to move forward as $e^c\cos c+1=0$ for some $c\in(a, b)$ will require $e^c\sin c-1=0$ for $c\in(a, b)$.

Answer (score 3):

Write the equation as $\sin(x) - e^{-x} = 0$, and note that the derivative of the left side is $\cos(x) + e^{-x}$.